# AWS EC2 Instance causing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on some networks, but works fine on others

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection, firewall

I am using an EC2 instance as a backend database server that receives open listings for an AirBnB type site. I've checked on my own browsers and phones and had others check on theres in other regions as well, and these listings load perfectly fine for us. There is one person in another region, however, who is not seeing any listings at all and receives the Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error instead. I even had them try clearing their cache in Chrome, but that did not help. Below are photos depicting the situation:

[Click here to see the problem page](http://locallockersite.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings) (lol)

Photos depicting errors:

[What I See/What Should Show Up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WztgA.png)

[Black Listings Come Up For Them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib86W.png)

[Here Are The Errors They Receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L2Uf.png)

[Here are the Inbound settings for my security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El8hi.png)

I'm thinking it may be a firewall issue, but i'm just not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can setup VPC flowlogs to see connection details, I would also suggest moving image, assets and JS to cloudfront as a CDN. YOU SHOULD NOT HAVE SSH OPEN TO THE WORLD. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html

Comment: @strongjz thank you, i've removed the open ssh's! I had all the front-end stuff on S3 and only the MongoDB database is in the EC2 instance.

Comment: So the network issue is from frontend in S3 to the ec2 mongoDB?

Comment: Yes, I believe so! I'm thinking the network at their school is blocking port 3001, though I am using it through nginx.

Comment: Setup a VPC Endpoint so S3 communication stays inside the VPC. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you check the security group in which your machine is, since it's possible that you're not allowing traffic to reach your machines.

it's possible that your location IP is open to the API but not other IP's.

I've tried to reach your page from my place and it's timing out as well, that points to the security group.

if possible share a screenshot of the security group set up on your machine, that will help diagnose further.

Comment: Just added the Inbound settings for the security group, let me know if that helps! Thanks!

Comment: I connected to the EC2 instance where MongoDB lives using the EC2 instance's public IP, could that be the issue? The site works fine for multiple people in Tennessee, Boston, and New York, but for some others in the same states but on different wifi networks the listings don't show up :/

Comment: i just checked from other network in mexico, which seems to be working.

it could be if you're trying to hit the mongoDB directly from the client side though i'm not sure how your app is configured, i guess you have a backend that connects to the MongoDB, if that's the case there shouldn't be a difference for the client (i would recommend anyway that you set up and internal network for that connection tho)

Comment: is there any chance you can get the ISP of the people for which the site doesn't work?

Comment: I ended up fighting it out, it was because their network was blocking the port 3001 so I did some nginx magic and it worked like a charm! Will add more specifics about the fix soon